# Verify that $\{\sin(n\pi x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, satisfies the following orthogonality condition.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Can someone check if my solution is true ? Thank you.

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi x)dx=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }n\neq m\\1&\text{ if }m=n\end{cases}$$

$\mathbf{m=n}$: $$\begin{align}&\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(n\pi x-n\pi x)-\cos(n\pi x+n\pi x)\right)\\&\implies\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\cos(0)-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\cos(2n\pi x)dx\\&\implies\frac{1}{2}[1-(-1)]-\frac{1}{2}[0-0]\\&\implies 1\end{align}$$

$\mathbf{m\neq n}$: $$\begin{align}&\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(m\pi x-n\pi x)-\cos(m\pi x+n\pi x)\right)dx\\&\implies\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\cos((m-n)\pi x)dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\cos((m+n)\pi x)dx\\&\implies 0-0\\&\implies 0\end{align}$$

Comment: @nullUser don't got to be so rude about it. I'm just trying to make sure it is correct and you don't know the reasons to why I'm asking so I suggest you can be kind and answer the question or leave it be and let someone who is kind to answer it for me,

Comment: I think your solution is good. Just use $=$ instead of $\implies$.

Comment: I think you should even extend it to a general interval rather than [-1,1] as given here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638308/orthogonality-of-sine-and-cosine-integrals